# The \vec command appears broken in Windows XP

Tags: support, mathjax

For example, when I write `\vec{a}`, I see (to be clear, the following is a screenshot):

$\hskip3in$ [image]

To facilitate comparison, here is `\vec{a}` compiled by the website:
$$\vec{a}$$

I'm currently using Chrome 17.0.963.56 m on Windows XP SP3 (I'm using an old laptop today). I tested it out on my phone (!) and `\vec` works fine, though. But I figure enough people are still using XP that it's worth mentioning this issue.

Comment: Font problem maybe? Refreshed cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that Chrome on Windows XP can't access four accents from the web fonts used by MathJax.  These are the combining arrow above (U+20D7), the combining dot above (U+0307), combining double acute accent (U+030B), and the combining long solidus overlay (U+0338).  The other browsers on XP (or any other platform) have no trouble with these, so I don't think it is a problem with the font.  Historically, Chrome on XP has had some problems with the web fonts with a few characters being inaccessible (a "T" in one font, a "d" and ">" in another, and several others).

I may be able to work around these four, but that likely won't be available until the next release of MathJax.  A quick check suggests that these are the only 
problems in the current version of Chrome on XP.

For now, you can try switching to SVG output (right-click on an equation to get the MathJax contextual menu, and use the "Math Settings" then the "Renderer" menu to select "SVG").

Comment: fyi: vec does work in XP SP3, Chrome 5.0375.99 (old laptop)

Comment: FYI: Still seeing this problem with Chrome 21.0.1180.75 and XP SP3.