# Chrome fails to render the `\vec` template

Tags: bug, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The \vec command appears broken in Windows XP](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/the-vec-command-appears-broken-in-windows-xp)

The `\vec` command seems to fail to render. Here's a pic.

[image]

The version is 20.0.1132.57 m

Comment: Are you using Windows XP? If so, this could be the same problem as [I reported here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3768/264).

Comment: @ZevChonoles Should've looked further. You can close as a duplicate.